# Does my POST edit action overwrite all fields in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

Say I have a database record with 7 fields and I just want to edit the contents of field 1. So I hit my GET EDIT action, it renders the strongly typed view with my viewmodel and I go ahead and update field 1. However, my POST action contains 'mapping' for all fields as below. So will entity framework **'overwrite'** all 6 other fields in the underlying database with the unchanged value or will it only just change field 1?

Just looking for further clarification after giving the previous related answer ([c# edit method overwrite all or only save changes fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21632148/c-sharp-edit-method-overwrite-all-or-only-save-changes-fields)) some more thought given that I am explicitly specifying each field in the edit method.

EDIT POST method extract -

```
db.entities.find(x)

            entity.field1= viewmodel.field1;
            entity.field2= viewmodel.field2;
            entity.field3= viewmodel.field3;
            entity.field4= viewmodel.field4;
            entity.field5= viewmodel.field5;
            entity.field6= viewmodel.field6;
            entity.field7= viewmodel.field7;

db.savechanges()
```

FYI - this is my first proper MVC app.

Many thanks

Comment: If you specifically overwrite a new value to a field then it will be updated otherwise you are already retrieving existing entity by some ID from DB.

Comment: what bout if the edit form value is identical to the currently persisted value? Does EF overwrite it or is it intelligent enough to know not to overwrite?

Comment: It depends if you have implemented ChangeTracking or not. Check this answer for more clarification on your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/17908807/2845152

Comment: thank you. I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205 from your link. Basically change tracking is default unless turned off (which I haven't) so my edit action will only change and save values that have really changed. thanks for your help